# Is there a regex to extract sections from this multiline string?

Tags: regex, erlang, regex-group, pcre

This is the input string

```
Some content here

%% some text 1

Some content here 1

%% some text 2

Some content here 2
```

I would like to get this

```
[
  "Some content here\n\n",
  "%% some text 1",
  "\n\nSome content here 1\n\n",
  "%% some text 2",
  "\n\nSome content here 2\n\n"
]
```

Or this

```
[
  "Some content here\n\n",
  "%% some text 1\n\nSome content here 1\n\n",
  "%% some text 2\n\nSome content here 2\n\n"
]
```

The brackets in the output are just to express a list of matches.

Is there a multiline regex (pcre) that allows me to achieve that?

Thank you

I tried this one `(%% .+)` with the multiline modifier but obviously it matches just the lines starting with `%%`.

Comment: Which language or tool do you use? Which OS? Are brackets needed in the output?

Comment: I am using the Erlang programming language, but that's just PCRE, so regex101 would work fine. OS is linux... The brackets in the output are not important.

Comment: Having `\n` in the output looks strange/weird. And why there's quotes in your output? How you expect a regex to add quotes? It's a search and replace, then you need sed or perl

Comment: I guarantee this is easier and a lot more maintainable with "line by line" parsing and just inspecting the first two chars of any given line for `%`.

Comment: If you want to match these lines starting in `%%` without newlines and remaining lines with newlines, you can use an alternation: [`^%%.+|\n*.+\n*`](https://regex101.com/r/lp39I6/1) in *multiline-mode*.

Answer (score 2):

A good idea is to use [`re:split`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#split-3) with a capture group because the captured part is returned too:

```
re:split("content1\n\n%%text1\n\ncontent2","(%%.*)",[{return,list}]).
```

that gives:

```
["content1\n\n", "%%text1", "\n\ncontent2"]
```